# How to remove columns from dataframe based on whether or not they exist as rows in a 2nd dataframe?

Tags: r, subset, data-cleaning

I would not be surprised if this has been asked before, but couldn't find the exact problem in my search.

My data consists of two data frames:

```
ID = c("patient1", "patient2", "patient3")
phenodf = as.data.frame(ID)
phenodf$status = c("sick", "healthy", "sick")
row.names(phenodf) = phenodf$ID

patient1 = c(1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5)
genes = as.data.frame(patient1)
genes$patient2 = c(2.3, 1.3, 3.3, 4.3)
genes$patient3 = c(3.3, 3.1, 3.4, 3.6)
row.names(genes) = c("ABC", "A2B", "DE5", "ZXY")

#remove healthy patients
phenodf = subset(phenodf, status!=c("healthy"))
```

Now I need to remove healthy patients from the "genes" data frame, but what's an efficient way of doing so?

So far I've been taking `t(genes)`, merging the dataframes to remove patients that aren't present in both, splitting the data, fixing the row names, and taking `t(genes)` again - but I'm sure there is a better way!

Update: Thanks to both of you, these ideas work perfectly and are MUCH better than what I've been doing!

Comment: are you still looking for an improv. (concern. upvote) or is it finished for you?

Comment: Yes your answer was great so I check marked it. Don't know why the other answer got deleted as it was helpful too.

Comment: he missread it a bit, but yes i agree its always interesting to see different approaches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
genes[, colnames(genes) %in% phenodf$ID]
```

Comment: yes, but he subsetted already in his last line of code `phenodf = subset(phenodf, status!=c("healthy"))` for non-healthy patients,...

Comment: true, missed that